# php how do I use fopen() while being able to edit files in the website directory as non-root user?

Tags: permissions, apache2, php

I'm running a local apache2 web server at `/var/www/`.

In order to use the `fopen()` function in php, the user and group of my site directory must both be 'www-data'. Problem is, when I try to edit files as normal user in the website directory, the normal user has insufficient permissions to write.

Answer (score 1):

To enable both your ordinary user and the php interpreter to read and write the same files - and assuming the `www-data` group already has read + write permissions on the files - you can add your user to the `www-data` group.

```
sudo gpasswd -a david www-data
```

This won't take effect until you logout and log back in again. Until then, you will be able "spoof" being in the `www-data` group with:

```
newgrp www-data
```

This will cause your shell to fork into a `newgrp` process, during which you'll have a new shell session with belonging to `www-data` group.
You can exit this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>